# Swipe issue for UIScrollView (iOS 8)

Tags: uiscrollview, swift, ios8

I wanted to design a scrollable buttons at the bottom of the screen (like the filters in Photo), which is a TOC (table of content) for many pages. I used to write similar code below (in Objective-C) works fine in iOS 7, so not sure whether this is my Swift conversion or iOS 8 problem.

```
    tocView = UIScrollView(frame:CGRect(x:0, y:self.view.frame.size.height, width:self.view.frame.size.width, height:thumbHeight))

    for i in 0 ..< pages.count {
        let image = UIImage(named:pages[i].name)
        var button = UIButton.buttonWithType(.Custom) as UIButton
        button.setImage(resizeImage(image, size:CGSize(width:thumbWidth, height:thumbHeight)), forState:.Normal)

        button.frame = CGRect(x:thumbWidth * CGFloat(i), y:0, width:thumbWidth, height:thumbHeight)
        button.addTarget(self, action:"selectPage:", forControlEvents:.TouchUpInside)
        button.tag = i

        tocView.addSubview(button)
    }
```

Everything works fine - except that the swiping don't always work. Half of the time when I try to swipe, it seems that the button below will take away the swipe and the swipe does not happened. It is only when I swipe very fast then the swipt might happened. I wish to be able to detect a proper swipe or tap. Anyone having similar issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I don't know how to do it in swift** but i had the same issue in objC so my resolution has subclass UIScrollView and add this :

```
- (BOOL)touchesShouldBegin:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event inContentView:(UIView *)view
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    if(touch.phase == UITouchPhaseMoved)
    {
        return NO;
    }
    else
    {
        return [super touchesShouldBegin:touches withEvent:event inContentView:view];
    }
}
```

*edit*

After several tests I found a problem, Sometimes UIButton action isn't called... so I replace the method to *touchesShouldCancelInContentView* and worked better... y can try

```
- (BOOL)touchesShouldCancelInContentView:(UIView *)view {
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: I have converted it to Swift.